# Synchronise files between Eclipse and FTP Site

Tags: eclipse, ftp, synchronization

I am currently coding with Eclipse PDT, and I need to synchronise the files on my workstation with the files on the FTP server.

I've installed RSE, but I can only download and edit files as far as I can see it. What I want to happen is when I hit save, the file is saved locally, and the file to be updated on the FTP site.

Any ideas of how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an ant builder on your project. See this [article](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-93_project_builder.htm) about how to do that. The important things you should know after you read the article:

- You can use [Ant FTP task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html) to
  transfer the files.
- You can define properties given by
  the Eclipse platform to get project
  root, list of changed files, change
  type (add, modify, delete) and so on.
  Use them wisely. You will need
  project_loc, resource_loc and so on.
  See picture at end to see how to get
  other available variables that can be
  passed to the script.
- Tune your Ant script, since if it run
  for each file update, then it can be
  slow. If it is slow anyway, then you can [create a builder plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_implement_an_Eclipse_builder%3F) for eclipse, which is not so complicated. I created some before.
- Be prepared, that ant script can get
  not only one file as changed, but a
  list.
  [image]